# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) Reading PNG Even Though I Have Permission

Tags: java, android, permissions, share

In my app I am adding a Share button through the ShareActionProvider class. I am trying to share a PNG which I pull from the file system. The problem is I get the following error thrown at me when I try to share it with the stock messaging app

```
com.google.android.mms.MmsException: /data/data/com.frostbytedev.wifiqr/files/QRCode.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

At first I thought it was my permissions but I have the following permissions in my Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The place where I try to get it from the file system is here:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "/QRCode.png"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                provider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

If you were wondering, he is the code where I save the image

```
String fileName = getFilesDir() + "/QRCode.png";
                etSSID.setText(fileName);
                OutputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `/data/data/com.frostbytedev.wifiqr` is your app's private directory then yes, your app has permission to read that file. You don't even need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission because it's "your" directory.

But once you share it with another app, that app needs permission to read the file as well. And that's per default not the case with files inside your app private directory. The error you get is from the MMS app having no access.

A simple way to fix the problem is to save the file to a place that can be read by every app. Essentially everything in [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

The next possibility is to make that file readable for other apps but keep it where you have it. [`File#setReadable(true, false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean,%20boolean%29) should do that.

---

`Context` also has nice methods to simplify creating files in readable mode.

```
String fileName = getFileStreamPath("QRCode.png").getPath();
etSSID.setText(fileName);
OutputStream stream = null;
try {
    stream = openFileOutput("QRCode.png", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
    stream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

...

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("QRCode.png"));
.. share
```

Comment: I did the .setReadable and now get ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @SteveSmith sounds like there is something wrong with your paths (or did you do that before you saved the file?) Added alternative piece of code to answer that should work